# Let $F$ be a field. If $F^*$ is a cyclic group, must $F$ be a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

Let $F$ be a field. If $F^*$ is a cyclic group, must $F$ be a finite field? (It's well-known that if $F$ is a finite field, $F^*$ is a cyclic group).

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: This question has been [asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/753437/11619). I am a bit reluctant to cast my vote for closing this as a duplicate, because it would cause an immediate closure. Summoning an overlord to merge the two, as the other one has no accepted answer.