# Suppose that $F$ is a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ and non zero elements of $F$ form a cyclic group under multiplication. Prove that $F$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**$1.$ Suppose that $F$ is a field of characteristic $\neq 2$ and that the non zero elements of $F$ form a cyclic group under multiplication. Prove that $F$ is finite**

**Attempt :** Let $F=\{0,a,a^2,a^3,..........\}$

Given that non zero elements of $F$ form a cyclic group under multiplication. Now, since, by definition, a field must contain the unity, $\implies a^i = 1 $ for some $i$. **As a result, This $i$ must be finite**. Only then, can we say that a unity $\in F$

$\implies H = \{a, a^2, ...., a^i\}$ are all distinct elements and all powers of $a$ with index $<i$ belong to this set $H$. For all, indices $>i$, the elements get repeated and belong to $H$ itself.

Since, $i$ is finite $\implies$ $H$ must be finite and as a result $F$ obtained by adding an extra element $0$ must be finite as well.

Hence, $F$ must be finite.

**Is my proof correct? What was the use of stating that $char~ F \neq 2$ ?**

**$2.$ Describe the smallest subfield of the field of real numbers containing $\sqrt 2$**

**Attempt:** A field is a commutative ring with unity whose each element is a unit (i.e. possesses an inverse )

The sub field test states that $H$ is a sub field of $F$ if and only if $H$ is a field in itself.

(a) Closure under multiplication - $(\sqrt 2) \in H \implies (\sqrt 2)^2 , (\sqrt 2)^3, .... \in H $

(b) Existence of inverse for each element - (a) $\implies (\sqrt 2)^{-1},(\sqrt 2)^{-2},(\sqrt 2)^{-3}, ..... \in H$

(c) Closure under addition -

$...+ \alpha_{-2} (\sqrt 2)^{-2} + \alpha_{-1} (\sqrt 2)^{-1} + \alpha_{0} (\sqrt 2) + \alpha_{1} (\sqrt 2)^{1} + \alpha_{2} (\sqrt 2)^{2}+..\in H$ where $\alpha_i \in Z$

Hence, the smallest sub field of real numbers containing $\sqrt 2$ is of the form $\alpha (\sqrt 2)^\beta ; \alpha, \beta \in Z$

**Edit:** Due to closure under addition, $ (c_1 + c_2 (\sqrt 2)^m)$ should have an inverse as well. Hence, I think , the smallest sub field should be of the form $\{a + b (\sqrt 2)^m \}$ where $a,b \in Q$

Is my attempt Correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that your smallest subfield contains $4$, but not $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: But, $4$ must contain an inverse too? and that's $1/4$ when we are referring to the sub field of real numbers?

Comment: Yes.  Also, Jyrki's answer points to another number not in your subfield.  His answer suggests the proper form of the subfield.

Comment: yeah, I realized I was missing something. So, I added some edits. Is the sub field of the form $\{a + b (\sqrt 2)^m \}$ ?

Comment: Re: the edited version. $(\sqrt2)^2$ is rational, so can be absorbed into $a$. You get all the numbers you need from $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$, $m=1$, but you need to prove closure under multiplication and closure under inverses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there are shortcomings in your attempts.

(i) The choice $i=0$ gives $a^i=1$, so you cannot conclude that $a$ is of finite order in thise way. The question has been covered many times recently. I recommend [this answer by blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/838273/11619).

(ii) I don't think the number $1+\sqrt2$ is in your set $H$, so $H$ is not closed under addition and hence not a subfield. Have you, for example, done an example in class, where the smallest subfield of the real numbers containing $i$ was described? Failing that, have you covered a result that shows what the *prime fields* are? These are the minimal fields: $\Bbb{Z}_p$, $p$ a prime number and $\Bbb{Q}$. The edited attempt is much better. The answer is, indeed, that the set
$$
F=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}
$$
is the smallest subfield containing $\sqrt2$. It is easy to show that this is an additive subgroup of $\Bbb{R}$ and that $1\in F$. What remains to be shown is that:

- $(a+b\sqrt2)(a'+b'\sqrt2)$ with $a,a',b,b'$ rational is of this form, and
- the inverse $$\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}$$ is of this form, whenever either $a$ or $b$ or possibly both are non-zero. Hint: rationalize the denominator.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't come across prime fields or the smallest sub fields of real numbers. However, I have come across examples showing the smallest sub rings containing a particular element.

However, I realize that $\{a + b (\sqrt 2)^m \}$ must have an inverse as well. Hence, the smallest sub field, I think should be $\{c + d(\sqrt 2)^m \}$ where $c,d \in Q$.?
Thanks

Comment: @VHP: I added some material and hints that should allow you to complete this task. You only need $m=1$, and have a few details to be checked.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your answers :-)

Comment: I have a query. Let $a$ be a generator of the cyclic group under multiplication. What if we choose only $i>0$? Then, $H= \{0, a, a^2, ..... 1\}$ . $a^i$ must terminate at some $i$ to give $1$ (unity)?

Comment: The reason for choosing $i>0$ can be argued like this - Since, it's a cyclic group, choosing $i$ from any direction should not make a difference to the cyclic group?

Comment: If the cyclic group happens to be infinite, you cannot constrain $i$ to positive integers only. The additive group $\Bbb{Z}$ is the basic example of an infinite cyclic group. But positive integers don't form a subgroup. You are, indeed, trying to prove that the cyclic group has to be finite. So you have to show that it is impossible for it to be infinite. Working under the contrapositive assumption that it is, indeed, infinite disallows the conclusion that $1$ has to appear as a positive power.

Comment: Oh got it ..I messed up :)