# the unit group of an infinite field cannot be cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is well-known that the unit group of a finite field is a finite cyclic group. But for infinite fields, e.g., $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, the unit groups are not cyclic. I heard this fact in my class and I'm trying to prove it.

Assuming the unit group is infinite cyclic with the generator $a$, I tried to show some element, $\frac{1}{a+1}$ or $\frac{1}{a^2+1}$ cannot be a power of $a$, but it doesn't seem hopeful. Could someone help me?

Comment: Check out in particular [Blue's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/838273/11619) in that older thread, where this problem was discussed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in fact, more is true: a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic.

If the field $K$ has characteristic zero, it contains $\mathbf{Q}$ as a subfield, and thus $K^*$ contains $\mathbf{Q}^*$ as a subgroup. Hence it is sufficient to show that $\mathbf{Q}^*$ is not cyclic (because a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic). Suppose $a$ is a generator of $\mathbf{Q}^*$. Then also $a/2 \in \mathbf{Q}^*$, but no power of $a$ can equal $a/2$ (consider absolute values).

If $K$ has characteristic $p$ and is an algebraic extension of $\mathbf{F}_p$, for every element $a \in K$ you can consider the finite field $\mathbf{F}_p(a)$ to see that the subgroup generated by $a$ must be finite.

Finally if $K$ is a transcendental extention of $\mathbf{F}_p$, is contains $\mathbf{F}_p(t)$ as a subfield, so $K^*$ contains $\mathbf{F}_p(t)^*$ as a subgroup, and again it suffices to show that $\mathbf{F}_p(t)^*$ is not cyclic. Again, for any purported generator $a$, consider $a/2$, but this time you argue on its degree.

Comment: Ah, no, in infinite cyclic groups, negative powers are allowed, so $1/a = a^{-1}$...

Comment: Ah, it was marked as a duplicate while I fixed this...