# When is the unit group of a ring R cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups

For some rings, the unit group is a cyclic group.  For other rings, that's not the case.  My question is, is there some method of determining whether the unit group of a ring is cyclic or not, short of actually examining the unit group?

Like is there a theorem of the form "If a ring has property P, then its unit group is cyclic?"

Answer (score 1):

For finite rings the question has been answered here:

[Is the group of units of a finite ring cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/is-the-group-of-units-of-a-finite-ring-cyclic)

The result is a list of six properties $A,B,C,D,E,F$. On the other hand, if $R$ is a field with cyclic unit group, then $R$ must be already finite:

[the unit group of an infinite field cannot be cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382996/the-unit-group-of-an-infinite-field-cannot-be-cyclic)

Comment: That answer only settles things for commutative rings.  What about non-commutative rings?

Comment: In general, there is no such answer possible. Even the question, what other groups besides cyclic ones can occur, is too difficult - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384422/which-finite-groups-are-the-group-of-units-of-some-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1).